# String replace/filter within Channel Entries loop

Tags: channel-entries, ee6

I need to escape some text within a channel entries loop so it doesn't break the JSON schema I created for each page:

```
{exp:channel:entries limit="1" channel="posts" }
  {title} //replace " quotes with \"
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Liquid and Twig make this easy but I don't see anything readily available in the EE docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance one of the following variable modifiers would do the trick for you?

:json
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/variable-modifiers.html#json

:replace
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/variable-modifiers.html#replace

Comment: That is exactly what I needed! I know there had to be some string filters but all I could find was the date format in the channel entries docs.